# parse $result as $item to separate PHP values

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have some values from a DB query that are all concatenated

```
foreach($result as $item) {
print $item->chvotes;
}
```

Output is sequence of votes from a Drupal Poll so example output might be 1020340312
Where votes cast are (for example)
10, 203, 40, 312

**I have to get them into a series of separate php variables that I can use elsewhere.**

The query I am using is:

```
$result = db_select('poll_choice','n')
    ->fields('n',array('chvotes'))
    ->range(0,12)
    ->condition('n.nid',$nid,'=')
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Need more info than that, how about some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your values are separated by commas... `,`

```
$values = array();
foreach($result as $item) {
    $values[] = explode(',', $item->chvotes);
}
```

`$values` will be an array of arrays containing the separated values.